# OAuth2 custom basic user model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-socialauth

**I am using rest_framework_social_oauth2**

I want to make a minimum change in oauth.User. Search to exchange AbstractBaseUser by AbstractUser and add PermissionMixin. But nothing works.

My app> **models.py**:

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin, UserManager

 class MyUser(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
      country_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
      objects = UserManager()
```

My **settings.py**:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL ='userTest.MyUser'
```

As indicated by tutorials, not did makemigrations and migrate.

ERRO:

> File "/Users/luisdemarchi/Git/django/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 277, in **get**
>       self.model._meta.swapped,
>
> AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'userTest.MyUser'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed. I'll put here a complete example for those who want to make an improvement in OAuth2.user. In our case we created the username automatically.

PS: Need create class AuthManager()

**userTest(myApp) > models.py**

```
import uuid as uuid
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractUser
from django.db import models

from rest_framework import exceptions

class AuthManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username=None, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Users must have an username')

        username = email.split("@")[0]

        user = self.model(username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, username=None):
        user = self.create_user(email=email, password=password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractUser):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    is_test = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = AuthManager()
```

**userTest(myApp) > views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from apps.userTest.models import User
from apps.userTest.serializers import UserSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: I received an error that apps.userTest is not found. Can you please throw some light on this?